# Tabbar items are empty

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, appdelegate

I've been online for about an hour now trying to find different ways to set custom images i have onto my tab bar. I am using a resizing class. it's `UIImage+ProportionalFill` if anyone is familiar with it. I am a bit new to Objective-C and I have little knowledge on using `AppDelegate.h` here is my code. feel free to rip me a new one because I'm sure its probably going to be a rookie mistake.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{      

// [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem5 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

UIImage *oldProfile= [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"];
UIImage *oldFeed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"feed.png"];
UIImage *oldSearch = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
UIImage *oldNotifications = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"];
UIImage *oldMap = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compass.png"];
UIImage *newProfile;
UIImage *newFeed;
UIImage *newSearch;
UIImage *newNotifications;
UIImage *newMap;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
newProfile = [oldProfile imageScaledToFitSize:newSize];
newFeed = [oldFeed imageScaledToFitSize:newSize];
newSearch = [oldSearch imageScaledToFitSize:newSize];
newNotifications = [oldNotifications imageScaledToFitSize:newSize];
newMap = [oldMap imageScaledToFitSize:newSize];

[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:newFeed withFinishedUnselectedImage:newFeed];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:newMap withFinishedUnselectedImage:newMap];
[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:newSearch withFinishedUnselectedImage:newSearch];
[tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:newNotifications withFinishedUnselectedImage:newNotifications];
[tabBarItem5 setFinishedSelectedImage:newProfile withFinishedUnselectedImage:newProfile];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
return YES;
}
```

*EDIT* the error I receive is:

```
 -[UINavigationController tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-       [UINavigationController tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
`
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What result does this code give you? The UITabBarController class reference states that, "tab bar items are configured through their corresponding view controller" -- so you shouldn't be doing this in the app delegate, each controller should provide its own tab bar item.

Comment: @rdelmar yea sorry, totally forgot to put the error. Its up there now

Comment: Do you not understand that error? It's telling you that what you think is a tab bar controller (self.window.rootViewController) is actually a  navigation controller.

Comment: I can get past the error if replace `      UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    ` with `     UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];    
`  but the images still do not show on the tab bar

Comment: That's a wrong way to do it. Your tab bar controller probably should be the window's root view controller. Why did you set it up in IB with a navigation controller as the root view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Refer Below link:

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes

in Above link there are no of example in it and there is a "CustomTabBar" folder. In that example custom tabbar is implemented.